# SSRS Count of column based on values in other corrs column

Tags: reporting-services, conditional-statements, sum, where-clause

I have a scenario, in which I have to put a WHERE condition in one column based on value in the corrs column. 
The situation is that I have two columns, say A and B. A has only one the values 1, 2, 3 and 4 (can repeat)

Now, I hard code 4 rows under column A with values 1, 2, 3 and 4. In the corrs Column B, I want a WHERE condition such that I sum all values in B for which A = 1 (from the non-hard coded columns).

Please help me with the WHERE condition expression!!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!AcolumnName.Value = 1, Fields!corrs.Value, 0))
```

IF this isn't what you are looking for, then please add more information to your question: either you SQL query or a picture of your report depending on where you want this calculated.